# How to remove top padding in a Table Cell

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, tablecell

Here is the styling and the table inside the render function.

```
const style = theme => ({

table: {
    maxHeight: '90vh',
},

tableCell: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    border: "solid",
    borderColor: '#000',
    borderWidth: 1,
    padding: 0,
}

})


<TableContainer component={Paper}>
            <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="simple table">
                <TableBody>
                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell colSpan={2} className={classes.tableCell}>
                            {
                                this.getOilIndicator(data)
                            }
                        </TableCell>
```

And this is the function:

```
getOilIndicator(data) {
    return (
    <>
    <Typography variant="subtitle1" align="center" >{"OIL LEVEL"}</Typography>
    <div>            
        <Grid xs
            item>
                {
                    this.getDevice(_.find(this.state.devices, { "id": 5 }), data)
                }
        </Grid>
    </div>
    </>
```

The problem here is that there's an unnecessary padding at the top even after setting the padding to 0. How to remove this padding. I want to place the text 'Oil Level' at the topmost part of the table cell but because of the padding, I'm unable to do so.

Comment: vertical-align:top?

Comment: vertical-align: top seems to work. Thanks!